# Flink: Operation: [get] for kind: [Service] with name: [my-first-flink-cluster-rest] in namespace: [default] failed

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink

I am following the [Flink official tutorial](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/deployment/resource-providers/native_kubernetes/#starting-a-flink-session-on-kubernetes) to start a session in native Kubernetes.

However, after running

```
$ ./bin/kubernetes-session.sh -Dkubernetes.cluster-id=my-first-flink-cluster
```

I got the following error

```
2024-03-13 10:38:20,826 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration           [] - Loading configuration property: taskmanager.memory.process.size, 1728m
2024-03-13 10:38:20,832 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration           [] - Loading configuration property: taskmanager.bind-host, localhost
2024-03-13 10:38:20,832 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration           [] - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.execution.failover-strategy, region
2024-03-13 10:38:20,832 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration           [] - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.rpc.address, localhost
2024-03-13 10:38:20,832 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration           [] - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.memory.process.size, 1600m
2024-03-13 10:38:20,832 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration           [] - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.rpc.port, 6123
2024-03-13 10:38:20,832 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration           [] - Loading configuration property: rest.bind-address, localhost
2024-03-13 10:38:20,832 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration           [] - Loading configuration property: rest.port, 8082
2024-03-13 10:38:20,833 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration           [] - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.bind-host, localhost
2024-03-13 10:38:20,833 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration           [] - Loading configuration property: taskmanager.host, localhost
2024-03-13 10:38:20,833 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration           [] - Loading configuration property: parallelism.default, 1
2024-03-13 10:38:20,833 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration           [] - Loading configuration property: taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots, 2
2024-03-13 10:38:20,833 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration           [] - Loading configuration property: rest.address, localhost
2024-03-13 10:38:22,968 ERROR org.apache.flink.kubernetes.cli.KubernetesSessionCli         [] - Error while running the Flink session.
org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Operation: [get]  for kind: [Service]  with name: [my-first-flink-cluster-rest]  in namespace: [default]  failed.
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:159) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.getMandatory(BaseOperation.java:189) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.get(BaseOperation.java:151) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.get(BaseOperation.java:83) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.kubeclient.Fabric8FlinkKubeClient.getService(Fabric8FlinkKubeClient.java:216) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.cli.KubernetesSessionCli.run(KubernetesSessionCli.java:112) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.cli.KubernetesSessionCli.lambda$main$0(KubernetesSessionCli.java:202) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:28) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.cli.KubernetesSessionCli.main(KubernetesSessionCli.java:202) [flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1561) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1390) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1295) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:416) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:388) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:336) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:300) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:185) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:224) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:108) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.java:88) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.connection.Transmitter.newExchange(Transmitter.java:169) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:41) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:94) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:88) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.okhttp.OkHttpClientBuilderImpl$InteceptorAdapter.intercept(OkHttpClientBuilderImpl.java:62) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.okhttp.OkHttpClientBuilderImpl$InteceptorAdapter.intercept(OkHttpClientBuilderImpl.java:62) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.okhttp.OkHttpClientBuilderImpl$InteceptorAdapter.intercept(OkHttpClientBuilderImpl.java:62) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.okhttp.OkHttpClientBuilderImpl$InteceptorAdapter.intercept(OkHttpClientBuilderImpl.java:62) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:229) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:81) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.okhttp.OkHttpClientImpl.send(OkHttpClientImpl.java:138) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.retryWithExponentialBackoff(OperationSupport.java:577) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:556) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:521) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleGet(OperationSupport.java:490) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleGet(OperationSupport.java:460) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.handleGet(BaseOperation.java:698) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.getMandatory(BaseOperation.java:184) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:483) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:472) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:160) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:111) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1382) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1295) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:416) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:388) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:336) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:300) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:185) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:224) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:108) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.java:88) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.connection.Transmitter.newExchange(Transmitter.java:169) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:41) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:94) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:88) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.okhttp.OkHttpClientBuilderImpl$InteceptorAdapter.intercept(OkHttpClientBuilderImpl.java:62) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.okhttp.OkHttpClientBuilderImpl$InteceptorAdapter.intercept(OkHttpClientBuilderImpl.java:62) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.okhttp.OkHttpClientBuilderImpl$InteceptorAdapter.intercept(OkHttpClientBuilderImpl.java:62) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.okhttp.OkHttpClientBuilderImpl$InteceptorAdapter.intercept(OkHttpClientBuilderImpl.java:62) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:229) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:81) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.okhttp.OkHttpClientImpl.send(OkHttpClientImpl.java:138) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.retryWithExponentialBackoff(OperationSupport.java:577) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:556) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:521) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleGet(OperationSupport.java:490) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleGet(OperationSupport.java:460) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.handleGet(BaseOperation.java:698) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.getMandatory(BaseOperation.java:184) ~[flink-dist-1.17.0.jar:1.17.0]
    ... 7 more

------------------------------------------------------------
 The program finished with the following exception:

org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Operation: [get]  for kind: [Service]  with name: [my-first-flink-cluster-rest]  in namespace: [default]  failed.
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:159)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.getMandatory(BaseOperation.java:189)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.get(BaseOperation.java:151)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.get(BaseOperation.java:83)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.kubeclient.Fabric8FlinkKubeClient.getService(Fabric8FlinkKubeClient.java:216)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.cli.KubernetesSessionCli.run(KubernetesSessionCli.java:112)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.cli.KubernetesSessionCli.lambda$main$0(KubernetesSessionCli.java:202)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:28)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.cli.KubernetesSessionCli.main(KubernetesSessionCli.java:202)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1561)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1390)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1295)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:416)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:388)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:336)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:300)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:185)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:224)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:108)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.java:88)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.connection.Transmitter.newExchange(Transmitter.java:169)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:88)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.okhttp.OkHttpClientBuilderImpl$InteceptorAdapter.intercept(OkHttpClientBuilderImpl.java:62)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.okhttp.OkHttpClientBuilderImpl$InteceptorAdapter.intercept(OkHttpClientBuilderImpl.java:62)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.okhttp.OkHttpClientBuilderImpl$InteceptorAdapter.intercept(OkHttpClientBuilderImpl.java:62)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.okhttp.OkHttpClientBuilderImpl$InteceptorAdapter.intercept(OkHttpClientBuilderImpl.java:62)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:229)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:81)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.okhttp.OkHttpClientImpl.send(OkHttpClientImpl.java:138)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.retryWithExponentialBackoff(OperationSupport.java:577)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:556)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:521)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleGet(OperationSupport.java:490)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleGet(OperationSupport.java:460)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.handleGet(BaseOperation.java:698)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.getMandatory(BaseOperation.java:184)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:483)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:472)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:160)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1382)
```

The software environment I use

```
$ java -version
java version "11.0.17" 2022-10-18 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.17+10-LTS-269)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.17+10-LTS-269, mixed mode)

$ kubectl version
Client Version: v1.29.1
Kustomize Version: v5.0.4-0.20230601165947-6ce0bf390ce3
Server Version: v1.29.1

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.

$ ./bin/flink -v
Version: 1.17.0, Commit ID: 69ecda0
```

And I am using k8s provided by docker-desktop in Mac. I also tried Flink 1.15 and 1.16 at the same time and I got the same error. I searched for this problem on the Internet and it seems to be a problem with the [k8s client](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/issues/2212), but this problem does not seem to be solved in the end.